# Searching equal operator in a text file in perl

Tags: perl

I've a text file which has equal symbol as shown below many times the start of the line. How can i extract such a line. I"ve tried the below code, but its not working. ANy clues as to why its not matching?

Text file line:

```
[==========] 10 tests from 4 test cases ran. (43950 ms total)
```

Code:

```
if (/^\Q[==========]\E/ .. /^\Qran\)\E/) {
        print "$i.Match Found:".$_."\n";
        $i++;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, have not tested, but should work. I HAVE tested the regex and it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (somefile, 'data.txt');

while(<somefile>) {
  chomp;
  if ( $_ =~ m/^\[==========\]/ ) {
    print "Match found: ";
  }
}

close (somefile);
```

For clarification purposes; `chomp` removes new lines from end of the line, and is not essential in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here
use strict;
use warnings;
while(chomp(my $line = <DATA>)) {
  if ( $line =~ m$^\[=.*?]$ ){
    print "Line which starts with [==] is $line\n";
  }
}
__DATA__
[==========] 10 tests from 4 test cases ran. (43950 ms total)
A line without the equal signs at the beginning
[==========] 4 tests from 2 test cases ran. (30950 ms total)
[===]A line with equal signs at beginning.
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/5AaBoP)

Comment: Given the question shows only equals characters within the square brackets, the match expression might be replaced with `m$^\[=+\]$`. If there may be other characters then the match expression `m$^\[=[^\]]*\]$` might be used - although all the escaped and non-escaped square brackets may be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the flip-flop operator which will match lines starting from the first regex and ending at the second one (or the end of the data). From the regex you're using, I don't think this is your intention.

To match a line starting with `[==========]` and extract everything up to the word ran you need to use a [capture group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches):

```
if (/^\Q[==========]\E(.*?ran)/) {
    print "$. Match Found: $1\n";
}
```

The brackets match any character up to and including `ran` then place them in the special `$1` variable. Note also the use of [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles), the current line number, to save you keeping count with `$i`.

If you wanted to extract just the numbers you could use:

```
if (/^\Q[==========]\E (\d+) tests from (\d+) test cases ran/) {
    print "$. Match Found: $1 $2\n";
}
```